# Tier Price at Cross-sell products

Tags: tierprice, cross-sells

At the moment tier prices are running perfectly at single products.
But when I'm trying to print tier price at cross-sell products, the price does not shows up.
It just don't echo anything out.

The php code I am trying to use is the following.

```
<?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>
 <?php $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
 <?php echo $_item->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Am I missing something maybe? :)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

`getTierPriceHtml` is not a method of the product model class. That's why you get an empty result. Try it like this:

```
<?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
    <?php $_block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setProduct($_item);?>
    <?php echo $_block->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or you can try this to avoid instantiating the same block each time.

```
<?php $_block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view');?>
<?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
    <?php echo $_block->setProduct($_item)->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However, there's some problems. If i use your examples, it only prints out the single product price in cross sell. So if the current viewed product's price is $4, all the crossell's products has the same price, $4. Any idea why? :)

Comment: Actually, if i use following code, <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_item['tier_price']); echo '</pre>';    ?> I get the single tierprice for each crosssell products, but off-course since it's an printed array, it's not formatted :P

Comment: @SimonDuun. Then you can use that value to style it as you want.

Comment: @SimonDuun. Try with the first option I suggested.